# Al compartir link en whatsapp no se muestra la imagen del preview

Tags: wordpress, whatsapp, enlace, meta-tags

el problema es que tengo una pagina que comparto a traves de un link en whatsapp pero al enviar solo aparece el link y no muestra la imagen del meta aunque ya tiene los meta: imagen; url; descripcion; etc. Intente agregando el meta < meta property="ya:ovs:allow_embed" content="true" /> al head y colocando una imagen menor a 300K y de 300x300 pixeles pero no funciona, alguien tiene una idea de que debo revisar.
Como nota adicional si funciona el link en facebook, el problema es en el app de whatsapp.

Estos son los meta que contiene la pagina:

```
< meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
< meta property="og:type" content="article" />
< meta property="og:title" content="Mi boda Esmeralda &amp; Arturo" />
< meta property="og:description" content="Estas cordialmente invitado" />
< meta property="og:url" content="https://site.com/black-married/" />
< meta property="og:site_name" content="Evento" />
< meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php" />
< meta property="article:published_time" content="2022-09-03T19:37:07+00:00" />
< meta property="article:modified_time" content="2022-09-13T02:05:18+00:00" />
< meta property="og:image" content="https://fiesta.lezlynorman.com/wp- 
    content/uploads/2022/09/FloraLunar-1.jpg" />
< meta property="og:image:width" content="545" />
< meta property="og:image:height" content="493" />
< meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
< meta name="author" content="admin" />
< meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
< meta name="twitter:image" content="https://fiesta.lezlynorman.com/wp- 
    content/uploads/2022/09/FloraLunar-1.jpg" />
< meta name="twitter:label1" content="Written by" />
< meta name="twitter:data1" content="admin" />
< meta name="twitter:label2" content="Est. reading time" />
< meta name="twitter:data2" content="5 minutes" />
```

Comment: Utiliza tinyPNG para reducir el peso de las imágenes, también cierra el espacio entre `< meta`

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias. Revisare lo de tinypng para reducir el peso de la multimedia de la pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre el problema, la pagina era muy pesada y tarda mas de lo normal para procesar el link, solo es reducir la multimedia de la pagina o darle mas tiempo para procesar el link en whatsapp.